# server not responding to WebClient using TLS 1.2

Tags: c#, webclient, tls1.2

Although I specific to use TLS 1.2 still server is rejecting the connection.

mycode here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zcVum2

Error: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            string url = "https://www.converse.com";
            wc.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache);
            wc.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            string result = wc.DownloadString(url);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the issue by changing to .net core, even there there is no need for SSL configuration